# Convert to dd/mmm/yyyy

Tags: php, date-format, date-formatting

I am retrieving date from MySQL in the format yyyy/mm/dd 00:00:00. I want to convert this date into format dd/MMM/yyyy in PHP.

Comment: three digit months? do you live on jupiter?

Comment: I guess he means JAN, FEB, DEC etc.

Comment: I presume MMM = Jan, Feb.... etc

Comment: @Otto: Three characters are used on this planet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use PHP's [date](http://php.net/date/) and [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime/):

`$formatted = date('d/M/Y', strtotime($date_from_mysql));`

Or use MySQL's built in [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d/%b/%Y') datetime FROM table`

Or, you can mix a bit of both flavours:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) timestamp FROM table;

$formatted = date('d/M/Y', $timestamp);
```

The last method is handy if you need to get several different formats on the same page; say, you would like to print the date and time separately, then you can just use date('d/M/Y', $timestamp) and date('H:i', $timestamp) without any further conversions.

Answer (score 5):

Although you specifically asked for a php solution you might also be interested in MySQL's [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

```
SELECT date_format(dt, '%d/%m/%Y') ...
```

Comment: +1 MySQL internally stores the date as a number; this way, you parse and format the date only once.

Comment: But I am using Select * <table name>.

Comment: And you have to use `SELECT *` ? It would work with `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(...) as myDate FROM ...` but then MySQL would transmit the date field twice and the advantage that the date field had to be formatted only once is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `date()` function in PHP ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)).

```
print date('d/M/Y', $row['tstamp']);
```

This applies if your date field is a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`. Remeber to wrap the field in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)), e.g. `SELECT ..., UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateField) AS tstamp FROM ...`.

Comment: The seconds parameter for date() must be a unix timestamp, not the text representation of a MySQL DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. Therefore you'd have to use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) function in your query, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get mySQL to convert the date to a unix timestamp

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field) as date_field
FROM table
```

Then you can pass that straight into PHPs date() function to get the format you want

```
date('d/M/Y', $row['date_field'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$d=date_create('2009-12-04 09:15:00');
echo $d->format('dd/M/yyyy');
```